# Replace comma by new line but keeping first column

Tags: linux

I am trying to sort some super long file that I have where I have infos about some genes on the same line but I would like them to appear on multiple lines, just like this:

```
Gene1    A,    B,    C
Gene2    A
Gene3    A,    B
```

But what I would like is:

```
Gene1    A
Gene1    B
Gene1    C
Gene2    A
Gene3    A
Gene3    B
```

I can easily replace the comma by newline with sed or tr but I am not sure on how to keep the gene name from the first column

Any tips?

Comment: Personally I would write a Python script to read the source data and write out the expanded information. A shell one-liner will probably be too messy.

Comment: Since there are multiple answers for this I have to ask - What tools do you have in your disposal.  Are you looking for a regex or code to do that?

Comment: I thought regex would be easier but python would be fine as well, I was hoping there will a simple one liner but yes it is potentially super messy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:

```
awk -F "[, \t][ \t]*" '{ first=$1; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s\t%s\n", first, $i; }' inputfile
```

From your example I guessed that the fields can be separated by a comma followed by tab or spaces or a sequence of tabs or spaces only. That's why I set the field separator using option `-F` to a regular expression.

For the output I used a tab to separate the first word from the other word.

If the file contains a line with one word only, the script will print nothing for this line.